# Javascript functions and returning JSON

Tags: javascript, node.js, function

While #1 returns the JSON object, #2 returns undefined.

How can I return data as JSON and access its properties (like data.username or data.email) ?

## 1

```
function username() {
    user.where('id', req.id).fetch().then(function (data) {
      data = data.toJSON();
      console.log(data);
    });
  }

  var adminJSON = username();
```

## 2

```
function username() {
    user.where('id', req.id).fetch().then(function (data) {
      data = data.toJSON();
      return data;
    });
  }

  var adminJSON = username();
  console.log(adminJSON);
```

Comment: I used Promise, here's the solution : http://jsfiddle.net/4ecu1g43

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are console logging adminJSON before the function has returned.  The function is being run async.

You will either need to pass username a callback function as an argument, use an async library, or username return a promise.